# How Export Kendo Grid data to Excel/CSV/ZipFile - alternative method

Tags: c#, excel, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, epplus

Let's say you have a kendo grid and want to export your data to Excel or a CSV file format.

With the generic Kendo method you will find out that it gets very hard as it also brings about lots of metadata. This will render large excels useless.

With the method below you will be able to export to Excel, CSV, taking into account for filters and others.

Answer (score 1):

First you define in the `cshtml` file the JS function andthe kendo grid:

```
    @section scripts{
    <script>
        function DownloadExcelFile(e)
        {
            if(e != "undefined")
                e.preventDefault();
            var grid = $("#mainGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            var parameterMap = grid.dataSource.transport.parameterMap;
            var data = parameterMap({ sort: grid.dataSource.sort(), filter: grid.dataSource.filter(), group: grid.dataSource.group() });
            window.location = "Report/GetSummaryExcelReport?" + "filter=" + data.filter + "&sort=" + data.sort + "&group=" + data.group;

            return false;
        }
    </script>
    }


<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center padding-0 inner">
    <div class="grid-area">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SummaryGridRowModel>().Name("mainGrid")
   </div>
</div>
```

After this, you declare in the controller a function that will generate the sorted data and call the helpers to generate the EXCEL/CSV/ZIP file.

```
    public FileResult GetSummaryExcelReport([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var query = DbContext.vwReportSummary.AsQueryable();

        var summaryGridRowModelList = query.Select(SummaryRequestsSelector);

        var dsResult = summaryGridRowModelList.ToDataSourceResult(request);    
        string fileName = string.Format("RequestDetailsExcelReport_{0}.xlsx", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"));

        ExcelFileCreator fileCreator = new ExcelFileCreator();

        //var result = fileCreator.CreateExcelFileFileStreamResult<SummaryGridRowModel>(dsResult.Data as IEnumerable<SummaryGridRowModel>, fileName);        
        var result = fileCreator.CreateZipFileFileContentResult<SummaryGridRowModel>(dsResult.Data as IEnumerable<SummaryGridRowModel>, fileName);  



        return result;
    }
```

Last but not least, define the helpers that will generate the EXCEL/CSV/ZipArchive file creators.

Excel File Creator helper

```
public class ExcelFileCreator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a FileStreamResult containing a Excel file in it
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of object in the object list parameter</typeparam>
    /// <param name="objectList">The object list enumerable. This contains the data for the Excel file</param>
    /// <param name="fileName">The file name of the Excel</param>
    /// <returns>FileStreamResult</returns>
    public FileStreamResult CreateExcelFileFileStreamResult<T>(IEnumerable<T> objectList, string fileName)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();

        var contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        try
        {

            ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(ms);

            excelPackage.Compression = OfficeOpenXml.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;

            var workSheet1 = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
            workSheet1.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection<T>(objectList, true);

            var firstRow = workSheet1.Row(1);
            if(firstRow != null)
                firstRow.Style.Font.Bold = true;

            excelPackage.SaveAs(ms);

            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            var fsr = new FileStreamResult(ms, contentType);
            fsr.FileDownloadName = fileName;
            return fsr;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ms != null)
            {
                ms.Dispose();
            }

            throw;
        }

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a FileStreamResult containing a zip file with the EXCEL file in it
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of object in the object list parameter</typeparam>
    /// <param name="objectList">The object list enumerable. This contains the data for the EXCEL file</param>
    /// <param name="fileName">The file name of the EXCEL</param>
    /// <returns>FileStreamResult</returns>        
    public FileContentResult CreateZipFileFileContentResult<T>(IEnumerable<T> objectList, string fileName)
    {
        var contentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip;

        using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
        {
            using (Ionic.Zip.ZipFile zip = new Ionic.Zip.ZipFile())
            {
                using (var package = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
                {
                    var workSheet1 = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
                    workSheet1.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection<T>(objectList, true);

                    var firstRow = workSheet1.Row(1);
                    if (firstRow != null)
                        firstRow.Style.Font.Bold = true;

                    zip.AddEntry(fileName, package.GetAsByteArray());
                    zip.Save(memoryStream);
                    var fcr = new FileContentResult(memoryStream.ToArray(), contentType); //NOTE: Using a File Stream Result will not work.
                    fcr.FileDownloadName = fileName + ".zip";
                    return fcr;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a HttpResponseMessage containing a Excel file in it
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of object in the object list parameter</typeparam>
    /// <param name="objectList">The object list enumerable. This contains the data for the Excel file</param>
    /// <param name="fileName">The file name of the Excel</param>
    /// <returns>HttpResponseMessage</returns>
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateExcelFileHttpResponseMessage<T>(IEnumerable<T> objectList, string fileName)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(ms))
            {
                var workSheet1 = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

                workSheet1.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection<T>(objectList, true);
            }

            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.GetBuffer());

            result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = fileName
            };

            return result;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a HttpResponseMessage containing a zip file with the EXCEL file in it
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of object in the object list parameter</typeparam>
    /// <param name="objectList">The object list enumerable. This contains the data for the EXCEL file</param>
    /// <param name="fileName">The file name of the EXCEL</param>
    /// <returns>HttpResponseMessage</returns>
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateZipFileHttpResponseMessage<T>(IEnumerable<T> objectList, string fileName)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var archive = new System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive(ms, System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                var newEntry = archive.CreateEntry(fileName, System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Fastest);

                using (var newEntryStream = newEntry.Open())
                using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(ms))
                {
                    var workSheet1 = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");

                    workSheet1.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection<T>(objectList, true);
                }
            }
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray());

            result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = fileName + ".zip"
            };

            return result;
        }
    }


}
```

CsvFile Creator helper

```
/// <summary>
/// Enumerator for the CSV file separator
/// </summary>
public enum CsvFileSeparatorType
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Values will be separated by a comma: ", "
    /// </summary>
    Comma
    ,
    /// <summary>
    /// Values will be separated by a tab delimiter: "\t "
    /// </summary>
    Tab
    ,
    /// <summary>
    /// Values will be separated by a semicolon: "; "
    /// </summary>
    Semicolon
}

/// <summary>
/// This class helps create a CSV file
/// </summary>
public class CsvFileCreator
{
    public CsvFileSeparatorType CsvFileSeparatorType
    {
        get
        {
            CsvFileSeparatorType csvFileSeparatorType = CsvFileSeparatorType.Tab;
            switch (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CsvFileSeparatorType"])
            {
                case "Comma":
                    csvFileSeparatorType = CsvFileSeparatorType.Comma;
                    break;
                case "Tab":
                    csvFileSeparatorType = CsvFileSeparatorType.Tab;
                    break;
                case "Semicolon":
                    csvFileSeparatorType = CsvFileSeparatorType.Semicolon;
                    break;
                default:
                    csvFileSeparatorType = CsvFileSeparatorType.Tab;
                    break;
            }
            return csvFileSeparatorType;
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a HttpResponseMessage containing a zip file with the CSV file in it
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of object in the object list parameter</typeparam>
    /// <param name="objectList">The object list enumerable. This contains the data for the CSV file</param>
    /// <param name="fileName">The file name of the CSV</param>
    /// <returns>HttpResponseMessage</returns>
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateZipFileHttpResponseMessage<T>(IEnumerable<T> objectList, string fileName)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                var csvEnumerable = CreateCsvEnumerable<T>(objectList, CsvFileSeparatorType);
                var newEntry = archive.CreateEntry(fileName, CompressionLevel.Fastest);

                using (var newEntryStream = newEntry.Open())
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(newEntryStream))
                {
                    foreach (var csvLine in csvEnumerable)
                    {
                        streamWriter.WriteLine(csvLine);
                    }
                    streamWriter.Flush();

                }
            }
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray());

            result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/zip");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = fileName + ".zip"
            };

            return result;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates a HttpResponseMessage containing a CSV file in it
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of object in the object list parameter</typeparam>
    /// <param name="objectList">The object list enumerable. This contains the data for the CSV file</param>
    /// <param name="fileName">The file name of the CSV</param>
    /// <returns>HttpResponseMessage</returns>
    public HttpResponseMessage CreateCsvFileHttpResponseMessage<T>(IEnumerable<T> objectList, string fileName)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(ms))
            {
                var csvEnumerable = CreateCsvEnumerable<T>(objectList, CsvFileSeparatorType);

                foreach (var csvLine in csvEnumerable)
                {
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(csvLine);
                }
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }

            result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.GetBuffer());

            result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/csv");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
            {
                FileName = fileName
            };

            return result;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generates an Enumerable containing the CSV data in it. First row contains the headers
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of object in the object list parameter</typeparam>
    /// <param name="objectList">The object list enumerable. This contains the data for the CSV file</param>
    /// <param name="separatorType">Enumerator for the CSV file separator</param>
    /// <returns>IEnumerable</returns>
    private IEnumerable<string> CreateCsvEnumerable<T>(IEnumerable<T> objectlist, CsvFileSeparatorType separatorType)
    {

        string separator = ", ";
        switch (separatorType)
        {
            case CsvFileSeparatorType.Comma:
                separator = ", ";
                break;
            case CsvFileSeparatorType.Semicolon:
                separator = "; ";
                break;
            case CsvFileSeparatorType.Tab:
                separator = "\t ";
                break;
        }

        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        yield return "\"" + String.Join(separator, properties.Select(f => f.Name).ToArray()) + "\"";
        foreach (var o in objectlist)
        {
            yield return "\"" + HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(string.Join(separator, properties.Select(f => (f.GetValue(o) ?? "").ToString()).ToArray())) + "\"";
        }
    }
}
```